# Implicit conversions in Python

Tags: python

For example, if I wanted to apply mathematical operations on objects in the following way:

```
class A(object):
     def __init__(self, value):
         self.value = value

     def __repr__(self):
         return value

assert(A(1) + A(2) == 3)
```

I am getting the following error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'A' and 'A'`

Is it possible to evaluate objects to primitives so that I can apply simple operations on them? Similarly how you could use `implicit conversions` in `Scala`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can implement [`__add__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__add__) to define addition on your class.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
       self.value = value
    def __repr__(self):
       return 'A(%r)'%self.value
    def __add__(self, other):
       return A(self.value+other.value)

>>> A(1)+A(2)
A(3)
```

This implementation assumes that you are only trying to add instances of `A` to other instances of `A` to get a third instance of `A`. You can write an `__add__` adaptable to what type of operand you need it to work for.

See also [`__radd__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__) and [`__iadd__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__).

Answer (score 2):

That depends on what you're trying to do. You can define the `+` operator by defining the `__add__` method:

```
class A(object):
   def __init__(self, value):
       self.value = value

   def __repr__(self):
       return value

   def __add__(self, other):
       return A(self.value + other.value)
```

then of course in your example code you're trying to compare it to an integer which also need to be defined - which is done by implementing the `__eq__` method:

```
   def __eq__(self, other):
       try:
          self.value == other.value
       except AttributeError: # other wasn't of class A, try to compare directly instead 
          return self.value == other
```

(implicit typecasts on the other hand is not available as far as I know)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there isn't enough context in the expression to decide what the objects should be converted to. Python has [various methods that can be defined on an object](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names) that implement various operators, including the [`__add__()`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__add__) and [`__radd__()`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__) methods.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't enough context to know that foo should be equivalent to foo.value, so with Python's philosophy [explicit is better than implicit](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/). You can certainly subclass `int`, but then the operators won't produce your new class, and the object itself would remain immutable (as numbers in Python generally are). Notably, ctypes such as c_int32 have a value attribute like your example but do not implement numeric operators.